# MongoDB retrieve entry java

Tags: java, mongodb

I hava a MongoDB, that looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57b16601494957499ae07619"),
"URL" : "some url",
"Text" : "some text ",
"Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-15T01:07:00.000Z"),
"RelatedActiveTopics" : [ 
    "apple"
],
"Language" : "en",
"PlatformType" : "NewsAggregator",
"Platform" : "Bing",
"SentimentScore" : 0.0,
"Source" : "Times Publishing Group",
"RelatedDomains" : [ 
    {
        "DomainName" : "Energie",
        "Confidence" : 1
    }
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            BasicDBObject dom = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
            BasicDBList relatedD = (BasicDBList) dom.get("RelatedDomains");

            List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();

            DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) dom.get("RelatedDomains");
```

This gives me as output the DomainName and Confidence, but I only need the DomainName, how can I get just the DomainName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try java 8 stream to output a list of `DomainName` values.

```
List<String> res = relatedD.stream().
       map(item -> (String)((DBObject)item).get("DomainName")).
       collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using for loop

```
for(Object item : relatedD) {
  res.add((String)((DBObject)item).get("DomainName"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `dbObject.get("DomainName")`

Comment: I have tried this already and I get an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [DomainName]